# Kafka to Snowflake - Failed to find any class that implements Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Attempting to connect to a Kafka cluster and write data to Snowflake from a topic.

**The error I'm getting is:**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector

available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector, name='com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector', version='1.0.0', encodedVersion=1.0.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/libs/snowflakeinc-snowflake-kafka-connector/'}
```

**The command I'm using to run (excluding the standard zookeeper / kafka start commands):**

```
/path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/connect-standalone.sh /path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/config/connect-standalone.properties /path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/config/snowflake_properties.properties
```

**What I've done so far:**

Updated plugin.path in `/path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/config/connect-standalone.properties`

with

```
plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/libs,/path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/libs/snowflakeinc-snowflake-kafka-connector
```

I've researched similar cases online, but while many of those were users who received the same error message, their desired connector wasn't listed in the list of available connectors as it is for me.

I initially tried placing the snowflake jar directly in the libs folder, then again as the entire package structure, but neither work.

After each attempt, I've stopped zookeeper / kafka and restarted them, but still get the same error.

I've done tests with the the jar paths added to PATH, but I receive same failed result.

**Where I've looked:**

https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/userguide.html#installing-connector-plugins

[Kafka Connect can't find connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412622/kafka-connect-cant-find-connector)

[Kafka Connect cant' find class of developed plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299578/kafka-connect-cant-find-class-of-developed-plugin)

[Kafka Connect failed to add MySqlConnector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835825/kafka-connect-failed-to-add-mysqlconnector)

https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb/issues/23

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/476

https://github.com/wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery/issues/109

[How to copy or configure kafka connect plugin files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120556/how-to-copy-or-configure-kafka-connect-plugin-files)

**Where I downloaded my connector:**
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.snowflake/snowflake-kafka-connector/1.0.0

I've been on this for a few days now, and I feel like I've tried all of these suggestions.  However, none of them work for me and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are there any other errors worth noting in the logging output?  Also, does your configuration file look similar to the sample here? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#standalone-mode

Comment: Just looked through the logs, and there are lots of INFOs and WARNs, but only that one error line.  I do see this, which is not an error but further confuses me: INFO Loading plugin from: /path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/libs/snowflakeinc-snowflake-kafka-connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:222).  For the config file, I heavily referenced the link you provided and found some examples online, so I'm thinking that it may be acceptable.

Comment: You should only need `plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/libs`, but it looks like it's being loaded fine from the logs

Comment: Maybe you could ask this person for help https://stackoverflow.com/q/59329007/2308683

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but you will find life easier if you use Confluent Hub to install the plugin - `confluent-hub install --no-prompt snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector:0.5.5`. See here for an working confgig https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/pipeline-to-the-cloud/docker-compose.yml#L67

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Thanks. I worked through that the other day. Do both the worker and the cluster need to have the Snowflake sink installed?

Comment: What do you mean by "the cluster"? Perhaps start a new question with context and I can help there.

Comment: Probably a mix-up of terminology on my part as I'm new to Kafka, but to keep it short: I am connecting to a separate Kafka server from my local workstation.  I thought the local kafka is called a worker and the remote server is a cluster.  A new question is unnecessary as it may not help me get closer to solving this one.

Answer (score 0):

From the [connector documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#id2):

> Copy the JAR files you downloaded […] to the /libs folder.

To make it into the Kafka command's java runtime classpath, the jar(s) need to directly be under your `/path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/libs/` directory. From your description, they appear to be inside of a sub-directory (`/path_to_kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/libs/snowflakeinc-snowflake-kafka-connector/`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue in the Debian "cp-kafka-connect" image.

While installing the connector plugins manually, I tried to:

1. Mount the connector plugin files through volumes and extract the plugins manually in the CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH.
2. Run `confluent-hub install` (once the connect POD is spun up).

Both of the above options required a POD restart.

To overcome this manual POD restart, you can directly use the following command to install the connector plugin from within the image.

```
confluent-hub install snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector:1.4.3
```

Once the coonnector plugin in installed, you can install custom connectors:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @ODX.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Note:
No other changes are required in CLASSPATH or CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH.